# astro onclick event not calling the function

Tags: reactjs, onclick, astrojs

I am trying to build a personal project in `astro`. For this, I created a header component that looks like this:

```
import { AlignJustify } from 'lucide-react';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import { useState } from "react";


const Header = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const buttonStyle = {
        backgroundColor: '#BFBFB1', // Background color
        width: '3.5rem', // Adjust width as needed
        height: '3.5rem', // Adjust height as needed
        borderRadius: '50%', // Make it circular
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    };

    const toggleVisibility = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
        console.log(open);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <button onClick={toggleVisibility} style={buttonStyle}>
                    <AlignJustify/> 
                </button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {open && <Sidebar open={open}/>}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

This `header.jsx` is being called inside the `Layout.astro`. The issue is whenever I click on my button, `toggleVisibility` is not being called, but when I initially set the value of open to `True`, I am able to see "hello" on my localhost and it's hidden when the value of open is initially set to `false`. For some reason my `onclick` is not working.

What might be the possible reason for this? There are no errors rendering in the console.

thank you